# This virtual machine scale set is already in use by pool

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I had created a virtual machine scaleset agent pool. After testing I have deleted the agent pool and the virtual machine scaleset. Again I have created a new virtual machine scale set with the same name created before and when adding it to the agent pool I am getting the error "This virtual machine scale set is already in use by pool"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To fix this issue delete manually the tag from the scaleset. You can do this via the Azure Portal. In the scaleset, click the Tags link on the left and delete the tags labeled

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: In my case deleting the tag allowed me to select the scaleset from dropdown, but an error occurred when trying to save. The actual problem was this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56622380/how-to-recreate-an-agent-pool-with-the-old-name-in-azuredevops